# Adapter to send external video source to iPhone/iPod/iPad dock in place of iPhone/iPod/iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, video, ipod, dock

A relative has a 3M MP225 video projector which they would like to use with their DVD player. However, the projector only has a proprietary connector for video input and only came with a 30-pin cable for connecting to an iPhone, iPod or iPad. A composite video cable is supposedly available but I've been unable to track down any supplier that actually has it in stock (and an eBay search for it hasn't had any hits in several months).

I've seen products that are designed to plug into an iPhone (etc) dock in place of the iPhone to provide an audio signal - for example [this device](http://www.7dayshop.com/bluetooth-transmitters-receivers/7dayshop-bluetooth-4-0-wireless-audio-receiver-with-aptx-30-pin-apple-connection-adaptor-music-receiver) is a Bluetooth audio receiver which allows any Bluetooth audio source to connect to an iPhone-compatible speaker or audio dock.

Is there any cable or other product that does a similar job for video, i.e. allows a video source to be connected to a device that was intended for an iPhone (etc), in place of the iPhone?

Comment: What connectors (rather than cables) does the projector have?

Comment: Good point, @PaulGilfedder. It only has a proprietary connector whose pinout I have been unable to discover. It's definitely not any standard video connector such as HDMI, DVI, Displayport etc.

Comment: Can you also post the specific model for the projector?

Comment: It's the MP225. I really have searched long and hard for either the connector pinout or a supplier who can actually confirm availability of the composite cable! 3M never replied to my enquiry...